# NGINX disable cache for service worker in SPA

Tags: nginx, single-page-application, service-worker, nginx-location

It is desirable to 'force' browser into fetching service worker file every time it needs it instead of loading from cache.
I'm using NGINX (1.21) to serve static files of my SPA and my initial configuration (default.conf) was:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

I used the following `location` block to disable cache just for `service-worker.js`:

```
location = /service-worker.js {
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache';
    if_modified_since off;
    expires off;
    etag off;
}
```

and after clearing application cache in Chrome DevTools followed by the hard reload the browser received 404 not found for `service-worker.js` but everything else went ok.

I tried different 'solutions' like moving the service worker block above default block, adding an alias, adding different headers, etc. but everytime it returned 404.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hours debugging and trying different solutions I found the problem.

The `location /` block has a `root` directive telling `nginx` where the static files are.
My assumption was that adding specific `location` block for service worker would apply everything in that block plus the default `location /` block. Looks like NGINX does not work like that so the easy solution was to duplicate `root` directive in both `location` blocks and after testing out it worked like a charm.

There is no need to repeat this information in every `location` block so the `root` directive can be moved under `server` block.

Final config file is:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location = /service-worker.js {
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache';
        if_modified_since off;
        expires off;
        etag off;
    }

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```